# findNavController().navigate(direction) does not work for View.OnLongClickListener, but it works for View.OnClickListener

Tags: android, view, kotlin, android-navigation, onlongclicklistener

Android Developer Canary 3.4, kotlin.

Found that View.OnLongClickListener gives a type mismatch. Isn't View.OnLongClickListener not taken into consideration for the new Navigation Graph in Android ?

```
private fun createOnClickListener(stationId: String): View.OnClickListener
{
    return View.OnClickListener {
        val direction = StationListFragmentDirections.ActionStationListFragmentToStationDetailFragment(stationId)
        it.findNavController().navigate(direction)
    }
}

private fun createOnLongClickListener(stationId: String, kindId: String): View.OnLongClickListener
{
    return View.OnLongClickListener {
        val direction = StationListFragmentDirections.ActionStationListFragmentToUpdatePriceFragment(stationId,kindId)
        it.findNavController().navigate(direction)   // <--- Gives error here
    }
}
```

The above two functions should behave the same, but the lower (createOnLongClickListener) gives a 'Type mismatch' error for the 'direction'.

Isn't support for navigation added for View.OnLongClickListener ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View.OnLongClickListener need return type as Boolean

Example:

```
val longClick = View.OnLongClickListener {

        return@OnLongClickListener true
    }
```

Comment: You got me !! (Didn't see your response until I answered mine, you wil get the credit )

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer. The OnLongClickListener actually needs a response if the request is handled:

```
private fun createOnLongClickListener(stationId: String, kindId: String): View.OnLongClickListener
{
    return View.OnLongClickListener {
        val direction = StationListFragmentDirections.ActionStationListFragmentToUpdatePriceFragment(stationId,kindId)
        it.findNavController().navigate(direction)
        true   // <--- Add true here to confirm it is handled
    }
}
```

...wonders of kotlin... ;)